# Get the layout from the target in NLog

Tags: c#, nlog

What I have a NLog configuration file.

```
LoggingConfiguration nLogLoggingConfiguration;
```

Then

```
foreach (var target in nLogLoggingConfiguration.AllTargets)
        {
```

I want to get the layout from the target, it seems in the memory. When I hover over it in the debugging time. I found:
[image: target]

What I want is

```
 ${message}|${exception:format=tostring}|${stacktrace}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all targets have layouts, so you have to get the items that inherit from `TargetWithLayout`, Then you can call ToString on the Layout object. An example:

```
foreach (var target in nLogLoggingConfiguration.AllTargets.OfType<TargetWithLayout>())
{
    string layoutString = target.Layout.ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(layoutString);
}
```

Comment: A follow up question, if the target is the type of `TargetWithLayout`. Can we add the rule as `var loggerRule = new LoggingRule(ruleName, LogLevel.Fatal, target);`?

Comment: I mean `var filter = new ConditionBasedFilter();
                            filter.Action = FilterResult.Log;
                            filter.Condition = "(level == LogLevel.Fatal)";
                            var loggerRule = new LoggingRule(ruleName, LogLevel.Fatal, target);
                            loggerRule.Filters.Add(filter);`.

Comment: @Love I think so. You've just go to add it to the LoggingConfiguration's LoggerRules collection.